# ffmpeg How to SCROLL (draw text) on an overlayed image not on the main video

Tags: ffmpeg, scroll, overlay

i want to draw a scrolling text with left and right margin over an OVERLAYED image .. like let's say a BREAKING NEWS Header and then below it the scrolling text.. but i dont want the scrolling to start at the point 0 .. i wanted to be bound by the image overlay position and margins .. i tried this code :

`ffmpeg -re -i lethal.mkv -i template.png -filter_complex "[1:v]drawtext =fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:fontfile='arial.ttf':textfile='test.txt':x=w-mod(max(t-1\,0)*(80)\, 2*(tw+100)):y=10[1v];[0:v][1v]overlay=30:30[over]" -map [over] -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://224.2.2.1:1234`

when i do that .. the text doesn't show .. or i'm guessing it's showing behind the image .. i don't know !  Any help please

Comment: i was able to make it work by adding -loop 1 before the second input .. now it is working .. but the speed is slowing down sometimes. it is like 0.720x

Comment: *"but the speed is slowing down sometimes"*. The encoding speed? The speed of the scroll?

Comment: The encoding speed..

Comment: Use a [faster x264 `-preset`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset).